# How to update same field of all documents in collection in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have this collection (not exactly what I have, just for example). I want to update all "numberOfViewsPerWeek" field into 0 just like reset.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("594d2359bf170b0828690bf7"),
    "owner" : ObjectId("594c126285f0922a985083c1"),
    "numberOfViewsSincePost" : 15,
    "numberOfViewsPerWeek" : 4,
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("594d709addb8691cf067fa73"),
    "owner" : ObjectId("594c126285f0922a985083c1"),
    "numberOfViewsSincePost" : 10,
    "numberOfViewsPerWeek" : 2,
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("764d709addb8691cf067fa70"),
    "owner" : ObjectId("594c126285f0922a985083c1"),
    "numberOfViewsSincePost" : 12,
    "numberOfViewsPerWeek" : 7,
}
...
```

I'd try to use update but it only update the first document, my code is this

```
Property.update({}, {'$set': {'numberOfViewsPerWeek' : 0}}, function(error, properties){

        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        }

        if(!properties){
            console.log('Something went wrong');
        }

        console.log('success update view');
    });
```

what should I do? thanks in advance

Answer (score 9):

I actually think a lot of people have problems with this.

You should include an option called `multi: true`.

**Ex:**

```
Property.update({}, {'$set': {'numberOfViewsPerWeek' : 0}}, {multi: true},
   function(error, properties){/* ... rest of the code*/
```

**[Docs:](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/)**

> By default, the update() method updates a single document. Set the
> Multi Parameter to update all documents that match the query criteria.

I don't know why they did this, I find it unintuitive.

In my opinion updating all documents should be the default.

Update for mongo >= 3.2: To resolve the confusion prefer using `.updateOne` or `.updateMany` which sets the `multi` flag automatically.